# What's the best solution, in Angular 2, to update a value of a component when you route to a different page?

Tags: angular

So I've got these layout (DIVs)

```
-mainContainer
--header 
--statusBar
--main (which contains router-outlet)
--footer
```

When I change page/route using 'this.router.navigate(...)' the only thing that change it's inside DIV.main, but I need to update some variable in statusBar.
So what's the best way (both are working)

1) using OnChanges():

```
import {Component, OnInit, Input, OnChanges} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'status-bar',
    templateUrl: './status-bar.html',
    styleUrls: ['./status-bar.scss'],

})

export class StatusBarComponent implements OnChanges {

  @Input() location;
  private statuses: boolean[];
  signupComplete: string = '/secure/signup-complete';

  constructor() {}

  ngOnChanges() {
    this.statuses = [];
    this.checkStatus();
  }

  get status() {
    return this.statuses;
  }  

  checkStatus() {
    this.statuses.push('/secure/signupBegin' === this.location);
    this.statuses.push('/secure/signupTwo' === this.location);
    this.statuses.push('/secure/confirm-id' === this.location);
    this.statuses.push('/secure/kyc-failed' === this.location);
    this.statuses.push('/secure/select-card' === this.location);
    this.statuses.push('/secure/custom-card' === this.location);
    this.statuses.push('/secure/signup-complete' === this.location);
  }
}
```

2) using @Input():

```
import {Component, OnInit, Input} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'status-bar',
    templateUrl: './status-bar.html',
    styleUrls: ['./status-bar.scss'],

})

export class StatusBarComponent implements OnInit {

    private _location;
    @Input('location') set location(data) {
        this._location = data;
        this.checkStatus();
    }
    get location () { return this._location; }
    private statuses: boolean[];
    signupComplete: string = '/secure/signup-complete';
    constructor() {
        this.statuses = [];
    }

    get status() {
        return this.statuses;
    }

    checkStatus() {
        this.statuses = [];
        this.statuses.push('/secure/signupBegin' === this.location);
        this.statuses.push('/secure/signupTwo' === this.location);
        this.statuses.push('/secure/confirm-id' === this.location);
        this.statuses.push('/secure/kyc-failed' === this.location);
        this.statuses.push('/secure/select-card' === this.location);
        this.statuses.push('/secure/custom-card' === this.location);
        this.statuses.push('/secure/signup-complete' === this.location);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a service. That is the only way to have component to component communication through your router outlet or also called sibling communication. Here are a few things that may help you...

1. official angular docs on services [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html). This is by far the best way to go.
2. And here is a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/6WFsnxv3jDsxcuc3AFYB?p=preview) from another answer where I use a service to send information to a nav component while within the `router-outlet`
3. Other options would include an event emitter or a subject (examples all provided on angular official site link that I provided above)

Comment: I don't have to comunicate something between two sibling components... 
I have to comunicate to the status-bar that its "[location]" @Input() is changed, getting the new one from "route.location" (or similar). 
As I said both of that snippets are currently working, I want to know what's the best between them.

Does Angular2 run every life-cycle every time you load a component (for that component) and it's less performant?
In my case I'm trying to understand if OnChange is a watcher and lower the performances?